# Что не так со словом «поздоровкайтесь»?

Tags: лексика, словообразование, разговорная-речь

Посмотрел одно видео на YouTube и услышал такое слово.
Слышу такое в первый раз. [Вот это видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnmaNvrRZM0).

Comment: [Поздоровкаться](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/поздоровкаться) (Викисловарь).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да все так со словом [*поздоро́вкаться*](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F):
в орфографическом словаре — *обл.* к поздороваться;
в БТС — ***св.**, нар.-разг*., = поздороваться.

*Выйди хоть **поздоровкайся** со своей конячкой, она тут во дворе стоит!* (Валентина Осеева. Динка прощается с детством).
*Да чтоб не тянулись ― смотри у меня! **Поздоровкались** ― и будет* (Саша Черный. Солдатские сказки / Кабы я был царем).
***Поздоровкалась** она за руку с Ельциным, походила туда-сюда с Черномырдиным да с Лужковым, закручинилась* (Григорий Горин. Иронические мемуары).

Существует такой глагол в лексиконе, простецкий только.
Имеется он и в словаре русских народных говоров, довольно распространен (*обл.*, [стр. 328](https://iling.spb.ru/vocabula/srng/srng_28.pdf)).
С таким же значением есть и другие глаголы (не столь распространенные):
*поздоро́виться, поздоро́вываться, поздра́воваться, поздра́встваться.*